# One to Many Self-Referencing relation SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, one-to-many

I am pretty new in python (less than a day!). 
I am trying to build a Restful API using Flask. I have the class `class TaskModel(db.Model):` which has a self-referencing relation to the task. 
Actually, a task can have many predecessors (dependsOn field).

But when I add the relation below I got this error: 
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship TaskModel.dependsOn - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.`

My whole Task class is below:

```
class TaskModel(db.Model):
    """
    Task Model
    """

    # table name
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    earliestStart = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    latestEnd = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    dnetworkId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dnetworks.id'), nullable=False)
    dependsOn = db.relationship('TaskModel', backref='tasks',remote_side=[id], lazy=True)


....

class TaskSchema(Schema):
    """
    Task Schema
    """
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    department = fields.Str(required=True)
    earliestStart = fields.Str(required=True)
    latestEnd = fields.Str(required=True)
    dnetworkId = fields.Int(required=True)
    duration = fields.Str(required=True)
    dependsOn = fields.Nested('self', many=True, exclude=('dependsOn',))
    # dependsOn = fields.Nested('self', exclude=('dependsOn',), default=None, many=True)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In SqlAlchemy for relationship you should define both way, following is a complete working example of what you may looking for:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////{}/my.db'.format(BASE_DIR)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TaskModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    parent_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tasks.id"))
    children = relationship("TaskModel",
        backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    tm = TaskModel(name='Test1')
    db.session.add(tm)
    db.session.commit()
```

> Attention to parent_id and children, these combination of two will give you what you needed, a self relationship on tasks, on database a parent_id will be added to your table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question. 
In that case, can a task has many depends on tasks?

Comment: Here is the repo: 
https://github.com/pkontogiannis/dnet-python/blob/master/src/models/TaskModel.py

Comment: This is a tree structure and one-to-many, means, one parent task can have multiple children tasks under, if you need many-to-many (not a tree, it will be a graph) then it is a different story, based on what I see, tree should be fine.

Comment: but as I can see in your code, each task can have one parent (depends On). 
But in my case I would like to have multiple dependsOn.

Comment: dependsOn will be the children, just try it